# Array of NSManagedObjects has null values in it after passing it to another method

Tags: macos, core-data, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

In my app I'm using MagicalRecord for CoreData stack and I'm having a weird behavior of NSManagedObject. I have this method in my DB class that fetches all the entries of the Stuff entity from DB. I'm calling this method from another class, and inside of this getStuff method I'm getting correct values that getting print out in the log statement below.

```
-(NSArray*) getStuff
{
    NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:self.psc];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Stuff"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"idNumber" ascending:YES];

    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *arr = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (Stuff *stuff in arr) {
         NSLog(@"stuff fN: %@",stuff.idNumber);
    }

    if (arr)
       return arr;

    return [NSArray array];
}
```

However, the array that gets returned by this method to another class contains all these objects with null value in them.

```
// -- some othe class
// call DB to check if we have stuff there
NSArray* stuff = [database getStuff];

for (Stuff *stuff in stuff) {
         NSLog(@"stuff fN: %@",stuff.idNumber);
    }
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?! Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getStuff` method creates a new NSManagedObjectContext, which is (assuming that you compile with ARC) deallocated at the end of the method. Managed objects "live" in the context that they were created in. Accessing their properties after the context has been deallocated does not work.

Comment: This was really helpful. Did solve my problem, Thanks Martin

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you setup your CoreData stack with MagicalRecord you can use `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]` instead of `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:self.psc]`

Comment: I use to use it, but the thing is that I have two different stores (DBs) that I have to manage, that's why I'm using [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:self.psc] to distinguish the store I do the call for. Do you know the way I can do that differently?!

Comment: Ah, that way... Then i'm afraid you need to redesign your work with CoreData a little. As @Martin R mentioned, with ARC your context gets deallocated at the end of `getStuff`. You need to keep strong reference to your context inside the scope, where you work with its objects. If it's class - make context the property of class and initialize it with store coordinator in `init` of that class. If objects (and their context) are shared between classes consider creating singleton that keeps contexts for example in `contextOfDB1` and `contextOfDB2` properties.

Comment: Don't use contextForCurrentThread anymore. It's broke, and deprecated and is going away in the next release of MagicalRecord